# Mixture cure models in Python - code help

Tags: python, survival, lifelines, cure-models

I've been trying to fit mixture cure models in Python. My data has 3 columns: Time, Event_Status(1 and 0) and Cure_Status(1 and 0). I would actually like to extend this problem to a **multiple event mixture cure model**, but the code for that is even scarcer.

How can I fit a Weibull Mixture Cure model in Python using my dataset structure? I found the following code in lifelines, but I'm not sure how it ties into my dataset, nor how the lambda/beta/rho parameters should be initialized.

```
from autograd.scipy.special import expit
class CureModel(ParametricRegressionFitter):
    _scipy_fit_method = "SLSQP"
    _scipy_fit_options = {"ftol": 1e-10, "maxiter": 200}

    _fitted_parameter_names = ["lambda_", "beta_", "rho_"]

    def _cumulative_hazard(self, params, T, Xs):
        c = expit(np.dot(Xs["beta_"], params["beta_"]))

        lambda_ = np.exp(np.dot(Xs["lambda_"], params["lambda_"]))
        rho_ = np.exp(np.dot(Xs["rho_"], params["rho_"]))
        sf = np.exp(-(T / lambda_) ** rho_)

        return -np.log((1 - c) + c * sf)


cm = CureModel(penalizer=0.0)

rossi = load_rossi()

covariates = {"lambda_": rossi.columns.difference(['week', 'arrest']), "rho_": "1", "beta_": 'fin + 1'}

cm.fit(rossi, "week", event_col="arrest", regressors=covariates, timeline=np.arange(250))
cm.print_summary(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case, if it is "Cured", the event of interest will never happen and converge to a duration of inifinity. If it's the case, you just put your duration as the duree, the timeline as the maximum timeline you want to observe, and then "event" (not cured) as the event_col (0/1). The model will do the rest for you.

Also, you can see this problem as a competing risk problem. In this case, you can use a model that handle multiple events (censored = 0, cured = 1, event = 2).